# Running ASP.NET core web app from .net core console app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Let's say I've created a solution with 2 projects: ASP.NET Core Web Application and .NET Core Console App.

Is there a way to reference and run web application from console app?

**Specifically:**

How do I publish a .Net Core console app to a web server running IIS?

Comment: ASP.NET Core itself is a console app. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to launch a website from a different project that has referenced website's project. But unfortunately it won't just work out of the box by simply calling the same Main() fucntion stuff website's project is calling. I wonder how do I configure console project to properly run a website from the referenced project.

Comment: Is this so that you can start the ASP.NET Core server on demand?

Comment: I'm also facing the same challenge. The Server that I need to deploy to depends on IIS.

Comment: @ScottNimrod have you had a chance to look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @NoEscape have you had a chance to look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Thanks Nkosi. There's a lot of information to parse through. A lot of it seems very foreign to me due to me not being a web developer. I'll try to figure out the answer from what you've shared though. Thanks again.

Comment: Found this: https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/

Comment: @ScottNimrod I believe that link you provided should be enough to get you what you want. nice find.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have killed my entire Sunday still not knowing how to deploy. I'm missing the "Publish" menu item for the project that every site refers to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621165/unable-to-observe-publish-menu-item-in-vs2017-for-net-core-app

Comment: @ScottNimrod: Your project is in F#. The tooling in Visual Studio for F# ASP.NET Core projects is not finished yet, so no menu item. You'll need to handle it through the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core apps are console apps. Run the following in the command prompt in the project directory:

```
dotnet publish -o publish-output
```

This will generate the shared publish files in a `publish-output` directory. You may now run it with:

```
dotnet project-name.dll
```

Once you run it, it will accept requests on a configured port. IIS (or any other server) can now be configured to work as a reverse proxy. You'd typically create a website in IIS, and move the files from the `publish-output` to the website's IIS directory and configure IIS to act as a reverse proxy to it.

Follow the [instructions at Microsoft Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x).