# Unable to observe "Publish" menu item in VS2017 for .Net Core app

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm unable to observe the "Publish" feature in VS2017 for my .Net Core web app.

My goal is to publish my web services to a remote host that runs IIS.

**How do I get the Publish menu item to show up on the context menu?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Visual Studio 2017 - 15.4.5 only supports publishing [F# on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/using-fsharp-on-azure/).
You can try Visual Studio 2017 15.5 Preview 4 that should support what you are asking or wait for full release. You can read more about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/announcing-f-support-for-net-core-and-net-standard-projects-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: VS2017 (15.5) Preview 5 doesn't support it either. I'm afraid I have an app that can't be deployed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy ASP.NET Core Applications to an IIS instance,

you first need to download and install ASPNETCoreModule IIS Handler on the Server 
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md#windows-server-hosting

This is what allows your IIS launch and manage your .NET Core App

When that is done, you need to "publish" your application. So from the Web Application directory, you run

`dotnet publish -o "C:\Temp"`

you can also enter any other Directory. Just copy the contents to the server and it should work

**NOTE:**

For older versions of .NET Core (1.x) with F#, you need to verify that you have the IISHandler middleware configured you'd do something like `app.UseIISIntegration()`

In some few cases, It also did not generate `web.config` files in those cases, you need to manually add them. Below is a sample of the `web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```